# check that the value of a variable is in a particular range of values

Tags: php

First of all I want to say I am not a programmer but I have been playing around with some simple php scripts today and I have a quick question for those in the know. How could I simplify the following code so it does not use all of those OR logical operators?

```
$number = "";

if ("$number" == 2 || "$number" == 3 || "$number" == 8 || "$number" == 10) 
{  
    echo ('Your number is ' . "$number");
}
```

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: Hint: Remove the `"` around your variables. They are not necessary. And: Language constructs like `echo` should not be used with parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you for the hints As I said this really is the first time I have ever tried messing with php so tips like those are very helpful.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you could do this:

```
$valid_numbers = array(2, 3, 8, 10);
if (in_array($number, $valid_numbers)) {
  echo 'Your number is ', $number;
}
```

p.s.: you don't need/it's wrong to put $number between quotes, since you're expecting an int.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the in_array stuff before but did not know how to apply it to my situation. Your example explained what I did not understand on the php.net page. Also, thanks for the tip on the quotes. I did not know it was wrong to add them to integer variables.

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
if (in_array($number,array(2,3,8,10))) {
     echo 'Your number is '.$number;
}
```

or

```
<?php
switch ($number) {
case 2:
case 3:
case 8:
case 10:
    echo 'Your number is '.$number;
    break;
case 99;
    echo 'Your number is 99';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, although quotations around your variables don't cause the code to break, you really really don't need them and in fact the only reason your code still works is because PHP has a strange system to match between strings and integers.

Anyway, one way to rewrite that code is as

```
$validNumbers = array(2,3,8,10);

if (in_array($number, $validNumbers))
{
    echo ('Your number is '. $number);
}
```

Technically, you could also do

```
if ((1 << $number) & 1292)
```

if you're into unreadable code. This works because the binary representation of 1292 has a 1 exactly at the binary digits 2, 3, 8, and 10.

Comment: +1! The OP states that he is not a programmer. Shifting is out of his scope, i think.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it simpler in a way that makes sense. I would keep it just like that.

EDIT: By "simplification" I would guess that you want to do less operations...

Comment: I meant a better way to write it so I did not have to have all the || operators. Nicc6's answer below is what I was looking for. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Kris: Note that the meaning of _"below"_, etc. its loses meaning very fast on SO. You better refer to a name only.

Comment: My personal opinion is that the "Array way" is not a better way to write it. For me, it's not native and it's not meaningfull. And creating a whole array an iterating in it just to match 4 values ...